# Meteor deploy erase public folder

Tags: meteor

on meteor i've just added a new feature to download some image in public/img/aSpecificFolder.

It works locally, but i've seen that each time i deploy on meteor.com using deploy command, it looks like that public folder is completely erased. Or maybe that the deploy remove the current app and install a new one. So it only keept the connection to db but all files are removed and put again.

What is the good way of doing if i want to store image on meteor.com ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using something like [collections-fs](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-CollectionFS). When you deploy on meteor it will clear your previous app and use the new one.

If you use something like collections-fs it lets you store your files in the mongo database instead, so they're not actually on the same server that serves out data.

This is also good in another way (scaling) since each virtual environment that hosts your app is able to access the files. If you store the files statically they will only be accessible on one of the servers.

For the moment meteor hosting (via *meteor deploy*) uses one server, but its likely it will be scalabale in future.

Comment: I didn't know collectionFs, i will have a look to that package. I didn't ask me how worked the deploy process until today. But i would not have the problem with another hosting provider. But it's so easy to work with the standard deployment system. That would be great to be able to declare folder that should not be modified during deployment process.

Comment: i tryed this : 
    var fstream = Npm.require('fs');
    var writeStream = fstream.createWriteStream(filename);
    writeStream.on('end', function funcCallbackOnWriteStreamEnd() {
console.log('on finish');
    writeStream.end(); // not sure it's usefull
    var id = myCollectionFS.storeFile(filename);
    annonce.fieldId = annonce.fieldId || [];
    annonce.fieldId.push(imgId);
        myMainCollection.update({_id: annonce._id}, {$set: {fieldId: annonce.fieldId}});
    });
    request(urlToFileToDownload).pipe(writeStream);

But it fails:

Comment: the file is well downloaded on fileSystem (specified by filename var), but in fact the end event is never called so i can not insert anything in the collectionFS.

I'm sure i'm not using the right way but i've read the CollectionFS API and i thought that it was

Comment: using CollectionFS with Fiber to mix asynchronous writeStream with CollectionFS storeBuffer is the right solution. Thanks for help